# Tracing Sieve of Eratosthenes using GDB. How to trace better?

Tags: c, primes

I was trying the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), algorithm, which is used to generate prime numbers upto a given number "n" and in turn came across a code in the internet:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LIMIT 1500000 /*size of integers array*/
#define PRIMES 100000 /*size of primes array*/

int main(){
    int i,j,numbers[LIMIT];
    int primes[PRIMES];

    /*fill the array with natural numbers*/
    for (i=0;i<LIMIT;i++){
        numbers[i]=i+2;
    }

    /*sieve the non-primes*/
    for (i=0;i<LIMIT;i++){
        if (numbers[i]!=-1){
            for (j=2*numbers[i]-2;j<limit;j+=numbers[i])
                numbers[j]=-1;

     /* An alternate can be: for(j=i+numbers[i]; j<20; j+=arr[i])*/
        }
    }

    /*transfer the primes to their own array*/
    j = 0;
    for (i=0;i<LIMIT&&j<PRIMES;i++)
        if (numbers[i]!=-1)
            primes[j++] = numbers[i];

    /*print*/
    for (i=0;i<PRIMES;i++)
        printf("%d\n",primes[i]);

return 0;
}
```

Unable to understand the inner for loop for the sieving part i tried to trace it using GDB, to see what does the output show for `for (j=2*numbers[i]-2;j<limit;j+=numbers[i])` but it becomes difficult.

Can someone kindly:

> a) Help me to understand that statement? 
>   (j=2*numbers[i]-2;j
>
> b) Is there any way GDB can parallely show all stack contents as well
>   as execution output?    Using breakpoint and using `print var` looks
>   difficult. I mean it should i, numbers[i], j at one breakpoint or
>   better more detailed output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (i=0;i<LIMIT;i++){
    numbers[i]=i+2;
}
```

Number `n` goes into slot `n - 2` (for `n >= 2`).

```
for (j=2*numbers[i]-2;j<limit;j+=numbers[i])
```

Remember, `numbers[i]` was `n = i+2`, so `2*numbers[i] - 2 = 2*(i+2) - 2` is the slot of `2*n`.

```
     numbers[j]=-1;
```

For all multiples of `n`, starting from `2*n`, mark the number as composite. (It's a poor sieve, using too much memory, and doing too much work crossing off.)

```
Examining the stack

backtrace
where
Show call stack.
backtrace full
where full
Show call stack, also print the local va-
riables in each frame.
frame <frame#>
Select the stack frame to operate on.
```

might help examining the stack in gdb.

Comment: Thanks, let me try to trace it as per your guidelines and get back shortly.

Comment: In the second iteration of outer for loop: i=1, j=2*numbers[i]-2=2*3-2=4, numbers[4]=6, which gets cancelled. Now the inner for loop increments and puts j = j+numbers[i] = 4 + numbers[1] = 4 + 3 = 7, and numbers[7]=9. How come? I mean i thought it is trying to cancel the multiples of 2's first. What is the strategy it is using? I think a much simpler startegy would be just pick up a number from the array, if not -1, just keep on incrementing it every value found, eg if 2 found, increment every 2 time and cancel, if 3 found, increment every 3 times from that number, which is the way wiki shows.

Comment: The multiples of 2 are crossed out for `i == 0`, `numbers[0] == 2`. Then `j = 2*numbers[0] - 2 = 2*2 - 2 = 2`, `numbers[2] == 4` set to `-1`, `j += numbers[0]` makes `j = 4` which corresponds to 6, etc. It could start the inner loop `for(j = i + numbers[i]; j < LIMIT; j += numbers[i])`, that would do the same. Probably less confusing, but there are many ways to skin a cat, and everybody has their own preferences.

Comment: Your this statement was the blast: `It could start the inner loop for(j = i + numbers[i]; j < LIMIT; j += numbers[i])` that clarifies everything, and even i was trying in a similar line. Thanks a lot.